# Writing in an Excel file from VB.net when you don't know the range name

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop

I want to write to an excel using row/column numbers instead of range names. The only way I've found to do it was with the .Cells property but I always get an error 0x800A03EC when I try to use it. I tried to simplify it as much as possible to figure out how to make it work. The code bellow works for "test1" and I get the error when it tries to write "test2". I'm running excel 2016 and the latest version of visual studio on W10

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Visible = True
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With xlWorkSheet
    .Range("A1").Value = "test1"
    .Range(.Cells(8, 8)).Value = "test2"
End With
```

Can someone help me figure out how to fix it or knows an alternative method to do it ?

Comment: `xlWorkSheet.Cells(8, 8)` returns an Excel.Range object, so just use `xlWorkSheet.Cells(8, 8).Value = "test2"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Range(.Cells(8, 8)).Value = "test2"
```

Take out the .Range(). All that line needs to be is:

```
.Cells(8,8).Value = "test2"
```